# Lag when scrolling on Mac in LyX

Tags: lyx, mac

I have a macbook pro (OSX 10.9.1) and i'm using LyX (2.0.6). After using LyX for a while it has suddenly started to lag when i scroll (trackpad gestures and mouse wheel). Have anybody encountered this problem and know how it can be solved?

Comment: Some have found that upgrading to [LyX 2.1 beta2](ftp://ftp.lyx.org/pub/lyx/devel/lyx-2.1/lyx-2.1.0beta2/LyX-2.1.0beta2+qt4-cocoa.dmg) has solved it. Some have found that it did not solve it.